# Determine whether and where a variable (attribute of an object) is accessed in C++?

Tags: c++, object, variables, attributes

I'm analyzing a quite large C++ project using Visual Studio. In the project, a variable is assigned a value, and I would like to know whether the variable is accessed later or not. In case it is accessed, it would like to see at which place the variable is accessed.

Please note that the variable is an attribute of an object, i.e., the value is assigned according to

```
dsp->filter.transfer_function = 4;
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

I have tried to use debugging option of Visual Studio like Watchlists etc.

Comment: encapsulation. Make it private and put a breakpoin in the getter.

Comment: Do you mean a getter as described in this article: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_encapsulation.asp) ? If so, doesn't this imply that I have to change my entire code s.t. it works with the new "interface"?

Comment: Possibly off-topic but... why do you need to know this?  What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Use global find and search to search all the files for "transfer_function", match the case and whole word.

Comment: Is the code accessing hardware?  Place a breakpoint at the location where it is set.  Write down the address of the variable.  Place a data breakpoint at this address.  This will only work on static, global or hardware addresses.

Comment: yes you will need to fix exiting code if you make that change, but it will pay off more than once. Actually I'd go one step further and turn `dsp->filter.transfer_function = 4;` into `dsp->set_filter_transfer_function(4);`.

Comment: Most debuggers (including VS) have a capability to set up a watch list - a set of variables (including members of data structures) or (if names won't be in scope) memory locations to be watched for changes - and to stop execution whenever a modification occurs.